# sqlite how to add value on conflict

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database with product name,product price and product counter.
Product name is unique,product price gets replaced everytime a new value is entered and the problem is the product counter.
Its default value is `1`,when a new product is entered his value is set to 1.I need it to increment whenever there is a conflict for the product name.So if `Cheese` is entered twice,the counter will say `2` and so on.
What i need it to do is when there is a conflict,add 1 to its value. I want to do it this way because i'll need this later.I'll need to add the inputed value to the table value on some other thing i plan to implement in my app.

How can i achieve this ? I'd like to keep doing it the way i'm doing it now,with the `contentvalues` method of inserting and not with the sqlite syntax(`INSERT,SELECT,etc`).Is that even possible ? Cuz i'm an absolute 0 at sqlite syntax.And also,i need it to have a method that i can call in other activities to insert into the database (like `insertCountry(Japan,10)`)

```
public class SQLiteCountryAssistant extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "usingsqlite.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "countries";
private static final String DB_COLUMN_1_NAME = "country_name";
private static final String DB_COLUMN_2_NAME = "country_price";
private static final String DB_COLUMN_3_NAME = "country_counter";


private static final String DB_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table "
        + DB_TABLE_NAME
        + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, country_name text UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE,country_price text,country_counter integer default '1' );)";
```

And this is how i insert :

```
public void insertCountry(String countryName, String countryPrice) {
    sqliteDBInstance.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DB_TABLE_NAME
            + "(country_name, country_price) VALUES('" + countryName
            + "', '" + countryPrice + "')");

}
```

Comment: i don't understand what are you trying to achieve (is this a shopping cart or something else?). BTW, if I insert 3 times Cheese with a price of €3, the result on your database will be: Cheese 9(price) 3(counter)? If i'm wrong, please modify your question and make it more readable.

Comment: Yes,it's something like a shopping cart.The database needs to save the product name(for an autocomplete field),the last price that was used for that product(for an autocomplete field as well) and a counter to know how many times a product name has been used.So if you insert Cheese 3 times the price will be 3 and the counter will also be 3.I also modified the way i insert data,edit will come soon.if you need more info,please tell me

Comment: i've edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your database class, but check [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29):

```
return this.sqliteDBInstance.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

If you are creating your column correctly, if there is a conflict, the new entry will replace the old one.

EDIT: after your last comment, all you need is an **update**: first query your database with the name of your item (check carefully if parameters are ok):

```
return this.sqliteDBInstance.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, DB_COLUMN_1_NAME + "=?", new String[] {productName}, null, null, null);
```

This will return a Cursor with 0 or 1 row. If there aren't row, you can proceed inserting data normally (don't forget to add your counter: is 1 on first insert):

```
public void insertCountry(String countryName, String countryPrice) {
sqliteDBInstance.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DB_TABLE_NAME
        + "(country_name, country_price) VALUES('" + countryName
        + "', '" + countryPrice + "', '" + countryCounter + "')");

}
```

if there is 1 row, your product is already on your database, so just iterate the Cursor, take the value on counter, add +1 on it and update your database with [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Comment: I don't need it to replace the old one...i need it to add 1 to the counter or add a specific value

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing a value to a specific cell is not available in sqlite. You have to read the current value of cell and add your needed value to it and replace it with the old one. You can use update method.

```
public void update(String countryName, String price, long id) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(dbHelper.COLUMN_1, countryName); // These Fields should be your
                                        // String values of actual column
                                        // names
    cv.put(dbHelper.COLUMN_2, price);
    database.update(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id " + "=" + id, null);
}
```

every time you're going to add a row to your table you have to read all it and check if the row exists.here is a method to retrieve all rows:

```
public List<TableRow> getAllRows() {
    List<TableRow> rows= new ArrayList<TableRow>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(Helper.TABLE_SITUPS, allColumns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        TableRow row = cursorToRow(cursor);
        comments.add(row);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return rows;
}
```

TableRow is a class for database table rows and contains fields stands for actual table columns.
with iterating this list and get "country" value of each one you can understand if that row exists or not.

These are basic concepts of sqlite databases programming. I recommend you to research a bit in this matter.

Comment: And how will my app know when to use insert and when to use update ? My user will enter for example Chicken.Maybe it's already in the DB or maybe it's not.

Comment: Would it be easier to do with `"INSERT INTO " + DB_TABLE_NAME + "(country_name, country_price) VALUES('"+countryName+"','"+countryPrice+"')" ` ?